# Is a call to a function with parameters not being atomic the reason why this code throws exception?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

mutex mut,mut2;
int *cnt;

void check_val(int val){
    static int prev=0;

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut2);
        if(prev>val)
        {
            cout<<"!!!!!! " << prev << " " <<val<<"\n";
            throw string("");
        }
        prev = val;
    }
}

void fnct(){
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);
        (*cnt)++;
    }
    check_val(*cnt);

}

void thread_fnct(){
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
        fnct();
}

int main()
{
    cnt = new int;
*cnt =0;
    std::thread t1(thread_fnct);
    std::thread t2(thread_fnct);
    std::thread t3(thread_fnct);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect that inside check_val() prev would euqal val from time to time but I wouldn't expect to receive out of order values if I pass the parameter as value. Can someone enlighten me?

If you pass val by reference void check_val(int &val) then things happen as expected, val equals prev as expected from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

**On using pass by value**

`t1` increases the value pointed by `cnt` and prevents any thread from increasing it until
 it does, then `t1` takes a copy to `check_val()` to check it not the var itself.

Hence at some moment we may have two threads one of them has a larger value and it may  reach the assigning point before the other one reach the checking point and the result  will be unwanted.

**On using pass by reference**

`t1` increases the value pointed by `cnt` and prevents any thread from increasing that value until it does, then `t1` takes the value pointed to by cnt to `check_val()` to check it.
At some point, you will have a data race because you may have two different threads `t1` at the increasing point, `t2` at the checking point but I think this won't hurt because it makes `prev <= value` whole time.

Hence the right way is to put `check_val(*cnt)` into the lock scope, as follows and then
you may use pass by ref or value (as u want). And u can use `atomic` vars witout a problems too (and use pass by reference of course).

```
void fnct(){

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);
        (*cnt)++;
        check_val(*cnt);
    }

}
```

Comment: You're corret about the fix but I was wondering why you get out of order calls to check_val(). As you can see both the check and assignment of the prev and val ar gurarded by mut2 mutex and it's not possible that two or more threads will execute that part of the code.

Comment: Also I run the loop with a bigger limit (100000000) and when I pass by reference I don't get the exception. What compiler are you using ?

Comment: @user1934513 u r right. itried to get the error again but i just failed. seems the error was related to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing `*cnt` by value, it's copied. It's possible for `check_val` to be called with three different values. Assume only two different values are passed: 1 and 2.

Assume that the thread that passed 2 reaches `mut2` first:

`(prev = 0) > (val = 2)`? No? Okay we're good. Then set `prev = 2`.

Now the thread that passed in 1 reaches `mut2`:

`(prev = 2) > (val = 1)`? Yes? Throw an error.

When you pass by reference, no thread can call `check_val` and "lock in" the value of `cnt` before it's changed.

---

## Is a call to a function with parameters not being atomic the reason why this code throws exception?

If you had a `std::atomic<int> cnt`, you wouldn't be able to pass it by value, because the copy constructor for `std::atomic<T>` is explicitly set to `=delete`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic

This would force you to pass by reference, which would prevent the original issue caused by passing by value.

Comment: As far as I can see, passing a reference wouldn't make the code valid, since you still have a data race going on (the easiest example of how that could go wrong, imagine an architecture where addition of ints is not atomic and you could see a torn write). There's also visibility problems going on since we lock on different mutexes. That said neither problem would manifest on x86 most likely.

Comment: If you lock the same mutex in both places, say mut2, you may get into a deadlock

Comment: @Voo Sure there is a data race but why is the data race behaving like it does? Since the increment of cnt is guarded by the mutex it can be viewed as atomic and what is passed to check_val() by value is a  monotonic increasing counter so check_val() can't receive a smaller value than on the previous call. The worst case scenario should be that check_val() is called multiple times with the same value but not with smaller values than the previous call.